# Book on memory from hardware perspective?

Tags: memory, books, system

Is there a good book that talks about memory (SDRAM, DDR, NVRAM, flash etc) from a hardware/system perspective? Most of what I've been able to find deal with memory at the transistor level. I am looking for overview of the different types of memories, power requirements and PCB guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I found a website that gives a very good overview of memory: http://www.pcguide.com/ref/ram/index.htm. Also has some good info on other components of a PC.

Comment: This is all PC memory, this does not give an accurate description of the different memory out there for the embedded world. If you had been more clear that computer(PC) memory like DRAM was what you were looking for you would have seen what you were looking for from answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking in the datasheets for the devices you are interested in. Many manufactures will also have application notes that have more general information.

Comment: Micron has some good app notes: http://www.micron.com/support/part_info/technotes. Any other good ones?

Answer (score 1):

There's always wikipedia, it gives a decent overview of the different types of memories. What is your application that you are planning to use the memory for?

Comment: I don't have a specific application right now. I'm just looking for a general overview so that I'm prepared. That said, wikipedia is always a good resource. But I'm hoping there's a resource that focused on hardware design.

Comment: You should spend time learning about the different protocol's in my opinion. I2C, SPI, UART are the biggest. They are followed by many other protocols that can be very specific to the type of memory you need. I would suggest reading about memory to find out what interests you, then research what interfaces are available.